# ListView cells not behaving as expected with caching options and IsEnabled settings on elements within ViewCells

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a listview that displays some information on the users payment history, and within each payment entry there are various elements that are displayed or not depending on the PaymentEntry object. The variables in this object are populated from an API call that returns Json then deserializes it into an observablelist of PaymentEntry type.

The elements in the listview cells can vary depending on two bools within the entries individually. So one might show a stacklayout that contains two labels, and another entry might not display that. I have the IsEnabled variable of these elements bound to the bools within the list of entries, as I'd expect the listview would be able to dynamically display the viewcells no matter if some of the labels inside the viewcell are disabled or not.

My caching method is RetainElement due to the variable nature of the cells.

Now, the problem is that the binding for IsEnabled doesn't seem to be working. All of the entries are enabled, regardless of whether or not the bool is true or false.

Another problem is that the caching strategy seems to be breaking the listview, it displays only about 8 entries with their elements visible, then the rest of the viewcells are all equal size and completely empty of the labels that should be inside them, whether they have a binding for IsVisible/IsEnabled or not.

Some extra background is that some elements are displayed/hidden with a converter on the bool, a negatebooleanconverter that I'm using.

```xml
        <ListView
            x:Name="MyListView"
            CachingStrategy="RetainElement"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
                                    <Label
                                        Margin="2.5"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                        Text="{Binding issuedDate}"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                    <StackLayout
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding isBoolOne, Converter={Helpers1:InverseBoolConverter}}"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Label
                                                FontSize="Small"
                                                Text="Sample Text"
                                                TextColor="RoyalBlue" />
                                            <Label FontSize="Default" Text="{Binding SampleStringOne}" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Label
                                                FontSize="Small"
                                                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                                Text="Sample Date"
                                                TextColor="RoyalBlue" />
                                            <Label
                                                FontSize="Default"
                                                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                                Text="{Binding SampleDate}" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding isBoolTwo}"
                                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="Small"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                            Text="Sample Number"
                                            TextColor="RoyalBlue" />
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="Default"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                            Text="{Binding SampleStringTwo}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="{Binding isBoolOne}"
                                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="Default"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                            Text="{Binding SampleStringOne}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
```

Expected result is that the listview will display the cells with varying size based on the data they have enabled. So, for example, if isBoolOne is true, the first stack layout would be disabled, and if isBoolTwo is true, the next stacklayout should be enabled, and since isBoolOne is true, the last stacklayout should be enabled. Instead, all 3 of these are displayed no matter what.

I've tried doing a debug to display each bool in console from the itemsource, and they are being read correctly with no nulls and varying true/false as expected. All of the string bindings display correctly. All of the bool bindings display true apparently.

The second problem is that with caching strategy of retainelement, only the first few elements are visible, the rest are blank. With recycle element they all display, but as I understand this would prevent variation of elements enabled in each.

EDIT: I should make clear I have omitted some of the XAML, including the ListView.ItemTemplate, DataTemplate, ViewCell, a Frame, and an AbsoluteLayout that encompass what I've shown. I did this to minimize the code shown and only display the problem areas.

Comment: You should probably use a TemplateSelector instead of reusing the same cell which hide/shows an entire layout depending on a bool.

Comment: Ill give it a try and report back in an hour or two. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Looks like that worked fantastically thanks for the help @Cheesebaron

Comment: To clarify for future readers: `RetainElement` should not be necessary for cells having different layouts. `HasUnevenRows = true` should handle that, regardless of `CachingStrategy`. If anyone does encounter a situation that works with strategy `RetainElement`, but not with `RecycleElement`, that should be filed as a bug - such bugs need to be fixed so that RecycleElement can be made the default in the future. (Or at least post the details as an SO question or Xamarin forum question.)